# Client fails to show cookie sent by Azure Function App in browser storage

Tags: azure, cookies, azure-function-app, httpresponsemessage

I have a function app that sets a cookie when reached:

```
[FunctionName("SendCookie")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendCookie([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post","head", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();
            var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("cookieKey", "cookieValue");
            cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
            cookie.Domain = "https://azurefunctionapp.azurewebsites.net";
            cookie.Path = "/";
            resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] {cookie});
            return resp;
        }
```

I can see in Fiddler the cookie is sent along with ARRAfinity. But I don't see it on firefox's browser storage:
[image]

Can someone share some guidance as to what i'm missing please?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, you just need to remove `cookie.Domain = "https://azurefunctionapp.azurewebsites.net";`.

I test it in my side with the same code with yours'(but without `cookie.Domain`)

[image]

And the result show as below:

[image]

Or you can also set the domain as `cookie.Domain = "azurefunctionapp.azurewebsites.net";`(just remove the `https://`), it will also work fine.